# Ordenação de Lista no Java

Tags: java

Se `Collections.sort(lista);` ordena a lista de forma crescente, qual comando posso usar para deixar uma lista na ordem decrescente?

Comment: Apresente um **[mcve]** do seu codigo para que seja possivel sugerir algo baseado no que ja fez, e para que a pergunta não pareça um pedido de código pronto, o que não é bem vindo por aqui.

Comment: @Articuno hexacampão Na verdade eu precisava só saber qual era o inverso de `Collections.sort(lista);` que acabei descobrindo que é `Collections.reverse(teste);` mas obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: Note que o método `Collections.reverse()` não vai ordenar a lista, como você sugere na pergunta, ele só reverte a ordem da lista, sem ordena-la.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem uma sobrecarga do método `Collections.sort()` que recebe como segundo parâmetro um objeto `Comparator` ([documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator))), e a própria classe `Collections` possui um outro método que retorna justamente um objeto comparador que impõe uma ordem reversa à lista, o `Collections.reverseOrder()` ([documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverseOrder())).

O código fica assim:

```
Collections.sort(lista, Collections.reverseOrder());
```